# VB - Split String of Serial Data and Log Separately Into Excel

Tags: excel, vb6, split, uart

I have a string of data in the form "X0507Y0512Z0413". I am using VB to read the data from a pic microcontroller, and load the data into excel using VB script found on web. I can  get the first line of data into the first cell of my spreadsheet in the form as above. However I wish to separate this string into three columns X,Y & Z and drop the letter from the beginning of each variable.  It would also have to read in up to 20 seconds of data at a time so each value would need to be appended to the previous. Here is my VB script thus far, I have tried the Split() command and received an Error 13 type mismatch.

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()

   Dim intPortID As Integer ' Ex. 1, 2, 3, 4 for COM1 - COM4
   Dim lngStatus As Long
   Dim strData   As String
   Dim xyzData As String

   intPortID = 4
   lngStatus = CommRead(intPortID, strData, 1)
   xyzData = Split(strData, "X""Y""Z")
   Range("A2,B2,C2").Value = xyzData


End Sub
```

I am a total novice so this may be quite a simple fix, so apologies if it seems trivial. Any suggestions would be great.

S.J

PS

Would it be made simpler if each variable were separated by a comma?

Comment: This is not VB.NET, looks like VB6

Answer (score 2):

The first problem is that `xyzData` is set to be a string. As you're populating it from a `Split` you need an array:

```
Dim xyzData() as String
```

I can't think of an easy way to do the splitting in VBA as you're splitting by a different character each time - its needs a bespoke function to handle it. The following works - my VBA is a little rusty, so it might be possible to make it neater, but I think it works:

```
Private Function SplitXYZ(strData As String) As String()

    Dim pos1 As Integer
    Dim pos2 As Integer
    Dim char As String
    Dim i As Integer

    Dim ret() As String
    Dim retCount As Integer
    ReDim ret(0)

    For i = 1 To Len(strData)

        'Get and check the character from the string
        char = Mid(strData, i, 1)
        If char = "X" Or char = "Y" Or char = "Z" Then

            'Set the positions for the new range
            pos1 = pos2
            pos2 = i

            'If the range is valid then add to the results
            If pos1 > 0 Then
                ReDim Preserve ret(retCount)
                ret(retCount) = Mid(strData, pos1 + 1, pos2 - pos1 - 1)
                retCount = retCount + 1
            End If

        End If
    Next i

    'Add any final string
    ReDim Preserve ret(retCount)
    ret(retCount) = Mid(strData, pos2 + 1, Len(strData) - pos2)

    SplitXYZ = ret


End Function
```

Using it is as simple as:

```
Private Sub Test()

   Dim strData   As String
   Dim xyzData() As String

   strData = "X0507Y0512Z0413"
   xyzData = SplitXYZ(strData)

End Sub
```

How you then use the split array is up to you.

One other thing: If you can assume that each piece of data in your string is the same length (ie 4 digits with the letter in front) then breaking the string down by length might be simpler, but you've not specified that this is the case, so I've not assumed it.

Comment: This works a treat, however will need to figure out a way to get each split string into respective cells, should not be too hard. Will update when have a result. Would like to thank Jon Egerton, your speedy reply and insight were extremely helpful, I commend you, thank you.